# How can I disable CapsLock during user login?

Tags: login

On my computer running Xubuntu 20.04 I block the key **CapsLock** by issuing

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

through `xfce4-settings-settings` on login.

I would like to have this key disabled even before, i.e. during the login phase.

CapsLock is not enabled in the BIOS by default.

I support a user who often accidentally presses CapsLock and then he can't log in himself. I would like to help him, as I have already helped him *after* logging into the system. - The **Insert key** is also a candidate that often causes avoidable confusion by causing the overwrite mode. This key is also easily pressed accidentally or even just pressed along.

**Is this possible?
How can I achieve this goal?**

`lightdm --show-config` gives me this:

```
a@W:~$ lightdm  --show-config
[Seat:*]
J  allow-guest=false
L  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
M  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
N  xserver-command=X -core
O  greeter-setup-script=xubuntu-numlockx
P  greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
Q  user-session=xubuntu
R  type=xlocal
R  display-setup-script=/sbin/prime-offload
R  display-stopped-script=/sbin/prime-switch

   [LightDM]
K  backup-logs=false

Sources:
J  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
K  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
L  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
M  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
N  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
O  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xubuntu-numlock.conf
P  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
Q  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf
R  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nvidia.conf
J  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
K  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
L  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
M  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
N  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
O  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xubuntu-numlock.conf
P  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
Q  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf
R  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nvidia.conf
a@W:~$
```

I first asked for a hook for commands to be carried out before the login procedure. One comment suggested to set up a crontab with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add the line

```
@reboot /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

Unfortunately this does not do the job. I could verify that the crontab actually is carried out (see my own comment below), but the invoked command `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:none` might be overwritten by the login procedure before it actually asks for the password. (Does it first reset all keyboard-configuration to some default?)

**What is the login procedure in Xubuntu 20.04? Is it `lightdm` or is it `lightdm-gtk-greeter`?**

**Would it be possible to issue the command `setxkbmap -option caps:none` from within some of the lightdm-configuration files such that it is effective when the password is input?**

Comment: To be clear on your computer caps lock is on by default? If so this is very unusual. Is there some BIOS setting that controls this?

Comment: No, it is not enabled by default. But I support a user who often accidentally presses this button and then can't log in by himself. I would like to help him, she as I have already helped him after logging into the system. - The Insert key is also a candidate that often causes avoidable confusion by causing an overwrite mode. This key is also easily pressed accidentally or even just pressed along.

Comment: Please add this info to the question with the edit feature.

Comment: One thing to try is to disable caplock as the computer starts. Try setting up a crontab as root using the command `sudo crontab -e`. Then add the line: `@reboot /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:none`. Save the file and exit. Then restart the computer to test. I have no idea if it will work, but it is worth a shot. If it works let me know. I will write a full answer for you to accept.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. When I pressed CapsLock, a fat upward arrow appeared at the right end of the password entry field. When I pressed it again, the fat upward arrow disappeared. When I typed my password with the upward arrow being on, the password was wrong. When I pressed Shift in addition during the characters in the password, it became right (for the non-alphabetic characters I had to press CapsLock again to make the upward arrow vanish. Unfortunately, this trick does not work.

Comment: Adding another command `@reboot date > /tmp/start.txt` I found out that on each start of the system, the command is executed. However, the part `@reboot /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:none` has no effect on the keyboard during log in!